Classification of Hamiltonians having the same set of solutions
Assume that we are given $2n$ the functions $q_k(t),p_k(t);k=1,2...,n$ all "sufficiently" smooth and invertible in a finite interval $t\in [0,t_{max}]$. My question is what class of functions $H(\{q_k,p_k\})$ can represent these $q_k,p_k$ as their Hamiltonian with $\dot p_k=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_k}$ and $\dot q_k=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_k}$?
For a very simple example let $n=1$ and for some fixed $A,B,\omega$,
$$q(t)=A\cos(\omega t); \quad \dot q(t) =-A\omega \sin(\omega t),\\
p(t)=B\sin(\omega t); \quad \dot p(t) =B\omega \cos(\omega t)\tag{1}.$$
Now define the inverse functions $t=\tau_q(q);t=\tau_p(p)$ in the time interval $t\in [0, \tfrac{\pi}{2\omega}]$:
$$t=\tau_q(q)= \tfrac{1}{\omega}\arccos (\tfrac{q}{A})\\t=\tau_p(p)= \tfrac{1}{\omega}\arcsin (\tfrac{p}{B})\tag{2}$$
and substitute them into $\dot p$ and $\dot q$ resp., so that
$$\dot p(t)=\dot p (\tau_q(q))=B\omega \cos(\arccos(\tfrac{q}{A}))=\frac{B\omega}{A}q\\
\dot q(t)=\dot q (\tau_p(p))=-A\omega \sin(\arcsin (\tfrac{p}{B}))=-\frac{A\omega}{B}p\tag{3}.$$
This lets us integrate the canonical equations immediately
$$\dot p=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\\ 
\dot q=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}.$$
$$\int dt \dot p(t) =\int dq \dot p(\tau_q(q)=\frac{B\omega}{2A}q^2=-\int dq\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}=-H(q,p)+f_p(p)\\
\int dt \dot q(t) =\int dp \dot q(\tau_p(p)=-\frac{A\omega}{2B}p^2=\int dp\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=H(q,p)+f_q(q)\tag{4}.$$
Adding and subtracting these two we get
$$H(q,p)=-\frac{B\omega}{4A}q^2-\frac{A\omega}{4B}p^2+\tfrac{1}{2}(f_p(p)-f_q(q))\\
f_q(q)+f_p(p)=\frac{B\omega}{2A}q^2-\frac{A\omega}{2B}p^2 \tag{5}$$
Following the suggestion of @ZeroTheHero in his comment, rearrange the above to
$$f_q(q)-\frac{B\omega}{2A}q^2 =-f_p(p)-\frac{A\omega}{2B}p^2 = K\tag{5a}$$
but here in Eq (5a) the LHS depends only on $q$ and RHS depends only on $p$, so it must be a constant $K$ independent of both $p$ and $q$.
When this is substituted back we get
$$H(q,p)=-\frac{B\omega}{2A}q^2-\frac{A\omega}{2B}p^2+K \tag{5b},$$
exactly as @ValterMoretti has written below in his answer.
One can make this process more general and more complicated. In Eq. (3) we substituted into $\dot p(t)$ and $\dot q(t)$ the inverse functions $t=\tau_q(q)$ and $t=\tau_p(p)$, resp., but that is not the only possibility. One may substitute for $t$ an arbitrary two-variable smooth function $t=\theta (t', t'')$ with the restriction that $t=\theta (t,t)$ and let $t=\theta (\tau_q(q),\tau_p(p)$. For example, we can let $t=c_1\tau_q+c_2\tau_p$ or $t=\tau_q^{c_1}\tau_p^{c_2}$ with $c_1+c_2=1$, etc. Now the integration of the canonical equations will not be as simple since the $p,q$ variables will mix but the integrals exist and will depend on the choice of the function $\theta(\cdot, \cdot)$. Each choice will determine a class of Hamiltonians whose canonical equations have the same solutions, and my question is what can be said about these classes given the $q(t),p(t)$ and $\theta$. Are they related to some kind of canonical transformation? As one includes more than one $q,p$ the choices grow and so will the various classes.
$$*****************************$$
For lack of sufficient comments space this addendum is to follow @ValterMoretti's answer below.
Here I show that the way I posed the problem there is no unique solution.
I start again with $-\dot p_k(t)=\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_k}\quad \dot q_k(t)=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_k}\tag{6}$ and write for the inverse functions $t=\tau_{pk}(p_k), \quad t=\tau_{qk}(q_k) \tag{7}.$
The one-variable functions $\dot p_k(\tau_{qk}(q_k)) = f_k(q_k), \quad \dot q_k(\tau_{pk}(p_k))=g_k(p_k) \tag{8}$
exist wherever the inverse functions in Eq 7 exist.
$-f_k(q_k)=\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_k}\quad g_k(p_k)=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_k} \tag{9},$ and writing $F(x)=\int^x dx' f(x')$ and $G(x)=\int^x dx' g(x')$ for the primitive functions, we can integrate these Equations 9 directly to obtain
$H(\mathbf q,\mathbf p)=-\sum_k F_k(q_k)+\sum_k G_k(p_k)+\text{const} \tag{10}$ as one of the possible Hamiltonians whose solution is the set of given time functions $\{q_k(t),p_k(t)\};k=1,2,...,n.$ This solution cannot be a unique one for we know that there are hamiltonians whose potential $V(q_1,q_2,...)$ is not given as the sum of individual one-variable potentials $-\sum_k F_k(q_k).$
The discrepancy between what Moretti and I have written is caused by Moretti's assumption that from $-\dot p_k(t)=-Y_p(\mathbf x)=\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_k}\text{ and } \dot q_k(t)=Y_q(\mathbf x)=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_k}$ we also know the tangent vectors $-Y_{qk} (\mathbf x),Y_{pk}(\mathbf x)$ at the phase space point $\mathbf x = \{\mathbf q, \mathbf p\},$  so that the canonical equations can be integrated when the functions $Y_{qk},Y_{pk}$ are given.
The problem is that these functions representing the tangent vectors are not given yet, instead we have to construct them for any give set of solution curves in the phase space and then to each construction indeed corresponds a unique Hamiltonian.
Not any set of functions will do, only those that satisfy the reciprocity conditions of mixed partial derivatives, such as,
$$ \frac {\partial Y_{qk}} {\partial q_j}=\frac {\partial Y_{qj}}{\partial q_k},etc..$$
that are needed for the unique integrability, but until we define these $Y(\mathbf x)$ we cannot integrate anything.

ps.: For any system of ODE given by $\dot {\mathbf x}=\mathbf v(\mathbf x)\tag {A}$ given a smooth $\mathbf {v(x)}$ there is indeed a unique solution curve $\mathbf x= \mathbf x(t)$ that solves Eq. A, the Picard-Lindelof theorem, but the uniquesness of its reverse does not follow, namely, that given a curve $\mathbf x= \mathbf x(t)$ there is a unique $\mathbf v= \mathbf {v(x)}$ with which $\mathbf x(t)$ solves Eq. A.

why exactly do you not combine the explicit expression for $f_q+f_p$ with the other terms in $p^2$ and $q^2$?

@ZeroTheHero it depends who you ask, some might say that because I was an idiot...

hmmmm… methinks you are out by a sign in the coefficients of $q^2$ and also $p^2$.  after all, $-1/4+1/2$ should be $>0$.

@ZeroTheHero $AB<0$

I assume you are working in a given canonical coordinate patch in the phase space.
If you know all the solutions of the Hamilton equations, you know their tangent vectors $Y(x)= (Y_q(x), Y_p(x))$ at each point of the phase space $x=(q,p)$. Up to a change of sign and components
$Y\to Z\equiv (-Y_p, Y_q)$
the Hamiltonian is the potential of this vector field:
$$-\dot p_k=Z_q(x)= \frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\:,\quad \dot q = Z_p(x) =\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}.$$
Namely,
$$Z(x)= \nabla_x H(x),$$
where the left hand side is known.
As a consequence, in connected domains:
the Hamiltonian of a given family of solutions (which admit Hamiltonian) is uniquely defined up to an additive constant.
If you permit Hamiltonians explicitly depending on time, this additive constant can be relaxed to a generic function of the variable $t$ only.
This proves how the notion of Hamiltonian is more rigidly determined by the equations than the notion of Lagrangian which is much more arbitrary.
Coming to your specific issue with the harmonic oscillator, your integration procedure is not correct. The first integration determines $H$ up to the unknown additive function $f_p(p)$. If you insert this expression of $H$ in  the second Hamilton equation, you determine $f_p$, and the Hamiltonian itself, up to an additive constant.
In summary, the possible Hamiltonians for the harmonic oscillator are the standard one plus an arbitrary constant.

thank you for correcting my wrong conclusion on the harmonic oscillator, the integration was OK but i did not finish putting it "back" to "H"; I fixed that text above. I understand your argument regarding the "rigidity" in a "connected domain" but did you rather mean to write a singly connected domain? If so, would the various $q(t),p(t)$ whose inverse functions are not unique create such multi-connected domain where H is not uniquely determined?

Connectedness is sufficient for the uniqueness statement: if a pair of scalar fields have the same gradient on an open connected set, then they differ at most for an additive constant.

please, see the added text below $*****$

It seemed to me that in the first version of your post you assumed the existence of a Hamiltonian and the issue regarded its uniqueness only. Under this assumption my answer is correct: if an Hamiltonian exists it is unique up to an additive constant. If you also want to study the existence problem you have to add integrability conditions. If you search my older answers on this subject you find an answer where I also considered these further conditions.

All that if the canonical coordinate system is given. Otherwise the problem becomes more intrigued.
